# modeling a very simple isA relationship : 2 tables with even/odd ids or 3 tables?

Tags: inheritance, orm, entity-relationship

We have two types of hospital staff in our project

- Doctor
- Nurse

and this is never gonna change (i.e. no other staff type). There is quite an overlap between the two entity types (e.g. login information are the same) but there is a large difference too . So far we can have:

- one `doctors` table with only even `id`s (2,4,6 etc) and a `nurses` table with only odd `id`s (1,3,5 etc)
- 3 tables, one to capture the common parent entity (`staffs`) and one table for each child entity (`doctors` and `nurses`)

I can't convince one of my colleagues that the first design is better in our project mainly because of its simplicity (specially fewer joins for common operations) and better performance. Why the first design is better ?

Answer (score 1):

First design is not better, since is a custom solution while second design follows relational databases principles.

EDIT: since you tagged the question with ORM, I suppose an ORM will do all the joining work. First solution can't be easily undestandable by an ORM, while second one is something an ORM can work out without any customisation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible ways to solve this:

Put everything in 1 table. Which is by far the easiest to work with (select * from personel where type = 'doctor'). Big downside to this is that all columns which belong to a certain type are unused for the opposite type (and visa versa).

Put it in 2 specific tables. Where both Doctor and Nurse have all columns they need to themself. In some way this is quite viable aswell as you can decide which one to select from. However, using odd and even id's makes no sense (where you thinking: Select * from tab_doctor, tab_nurse where id = uneven?). If you do use the id's like this and someone adds a even id to the uneven table you will get a problem, to prevent this you will have to write a trigger to check on the id (makes for worse performance).

The last possibility is using 3 tables as with the child entity's like you said. This one however use a lot of communication between the tables. And it's simplicity as you have stated is not on the level of the other 2 options.

Each implementation has upsides and downsides depending on quite a few factors (Not only the ones I mentioned, think of size of tables, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Party and Role model.

A Party represents an Organization, Individual, or perhaps an Automated Agent.

A Party can play many Roles. One such Role is a Nurse. Maybe the Nurse goes back to school and  becomes a Doctor.

If you read some Data Modeling books (Hay, Silverston, Fowler), this is the standard approach. It is good to use the standard approach if you don't have a reason not to.

```
PARTY
long id

INDIVIDUAL : PARTY
String name

ROLE
Party party
Date from_date
Date to_date

DOCTOR_ROLE : ROLE

NURSE_ROLE : ROLE
```

If you are using Single Table Inheritance, your tables would look like this:

```
PARTY
id 
type FK PARTY_TYPE
name
PK id

ROLE
party_id
type FK ROLE_TYPE
from_date
to_date null
PK (party_id, type, from_date)
```